Is there any difference between the expenditure for something and on something?
Is there any difference between the expenditure for something and on something? Which one is better?

The table shows percentages of consumer expenditure [for/on] three categories of products.


The table shows consumer spending. Expenditure is not right. Expenditure is money spent by an org. or company on something. You are getting a proofing free ride by breaking down your questions. Be that as it may, you are checking your terms.

Only this type of very formal economics statistics use expenditures: https://www.bls.gov/news.release/cesan.nr0.htm

Well, that's surprising. That phrase is in the TITLE of a table in an IELTS test. Even the IELTS trainer used the phrase. It's not even mine. See this. As for proofreading, I get that because people are nice, but I never try to take advantage of it. All of my questions here are my real problems and wonderings. It's conflicting how people complain about the lack of context when I don't give an example sentence, but when I do,you think that I try to get my text proofread.

Also, though I agree that often, it's the government's expenditure, I've found several examples from different dictionaries about individual expenditure. So I guess it is used this way, too. 1, 2, 3

this*

This is similar to your recent question about among and for.
The consumers spent their money on products.
The table categorizes those products and shows consumption data for each category.
The categories have an analytical existence.  The products have a real-world existence.
Consumers don't spend their money on categories.

Expenditure on is much more common, Cambridge uses 'on' as it's preposition in it's explanation of the word (Expenditure, Cambridge).
also TextRanch says:

Both 'expenditure for' and 'expenditure on' are commonly used phrases in English, but they are used in slightly different contexts. 'Expenditure for' is typically used when referring to the purpose or reason for spending money, while 'expenditure on' is used to indicate the specific item or category on which money is spent.

